# Populating Bootstrap Select2 From JSON Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I wanna code a bootstrap select2 with JSON data but somehow i cant get it to work.

here is my JS,

```
$.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(response) {
        var vendorList = $('#vendorListDrop').select2({
            processing: true,
            data: response,
            columns: [
                {data: "CLIENT_ID"},
                {data: "CLIENT_NAME"}
            ]
        });
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
```

Up to this point there is nothing wrong with the process_vendor.php since i can get the object data to work properly. Im just having problem with my JavaScript.

So the depiction that i need to populate is like this markup,

```
<option value="CLIENT_ID">CLIENT_NAME</option>
```

So i need to poplate value with CLIENT_ID column and displaying client name with CLIENT_NAME column from the database.

Please help me what im doing wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#vendorListDrop').each(function(index, value)
        {
            var initSelect2 = $(this).select2();
            var count = 1;

            $.getJSON('../vendor/process/process_vendor.php', function(data)
            {

                initSelect2.html('');
                $.each(data, function(key, val)
                {
                    initSelect2.append('<option value="' + val["CLIENT_ID"] + '">'+ count +' . ' + val["CLIENT_NAME"] + '</option>');
                    count++;
                });
                initSelect2.select2('refresh');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```